# Nuxt: EventSource works locally, but fails to receive data in deployment on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, nuxt.js, server-sent-events

We have a Nuxt project with a ExpressJS server which uses EventSource to get streaming data from the server. This works great from localhost, but when deployed on Heroku, no data is received, and the connection times out after 55 seconds with this error:

```
GET https://sse-test.herokuapp.com/api/sse net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)
```

The server receives the request and sends responses with res.write, but the client never sees them.

Here is the client code:

```
this.evtSource = new EventSource('/api/sse');
this.evtSource.onerror = err => {
  console.error('EventSource error', err);
}

this.evtSource.onmessage = e => {
  if (e.data === '[DONE]') {
    this.evtSource.close();
  } else {
    console.log('message', e);
    this.output.push(e);
  }
};
```

And on the server:

```
server.get('/sse', (req, res) => {
    console.log('enter sse');
    console.log('res', res);

    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    res.flushHeaders(); // flush the headers to establish SSE with client

    let counter = 0;
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        counter++;
        console.log('will res.write. counter', counter);
        res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify({ text: 'hi there', num: counter })}\n\n`);
        if (counter >= 10) {
            // this is also what OpenAI uses to signal end of stream https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-stream
            res.write('data: [DONE]\n\n');
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            // res.end(); // terminates SSE session
            return;
        }
    }, 800);

    // If client closes connection, stop sending events
    res.on('close', () => {
        console.log('client dropped me');
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Test project to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/ddett/sse-test

See this issue live here:
https://sse-test.herokuapp.com/

**EDIT:**

We tried with a plain Node/Express project (no Nuxt)... and this works great, both locally and on Heroku!

Code here:
https://github.com/madc0w/sse-express-test

Live test here:
https://sse-express-test.herokuapp.com/

So it seems the issue has something to do with Nuxt.